# Microsoft Graph api to get token api returns No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-adal-deprecation

I am getting No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource while trying to generate token using graph api in Angular 8 Application.

Is there any alternate way to manage this using microsoft-adal-angular6 npm to allow cors cross origins?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js#3-get-an-access-token

Comment: Yes, i have tried but while calling Graph API from Angular it throws No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Comment: please let us know which sample you are referring

Comment: I am using this package in angular application => microsoft-adal-angular6
Authentication is working but while calling Microsoft Graph API for token and getmembergroup using token generated from above package, it throws No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in below API

https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXX/oauth2/v2.0/token

Comment: can you please share the code of app configuration and graph call

Answer (score 1):

I think this question also has been answered [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65423470/i-want-to-call-token-api-from-microsoft-graph-in-angular-7-http-call/65434685#65434685). Let me know if you have any other questions.