# I want to call Token API from Microsoft graph in angular 7+ http call

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal

From angular application i want to call https://login.microsoftonline.com/##tenant##/oauth2/v2.0/token api to get access token from http call and using that token i want to call [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/##UserId##​​​​​​​​​​​​​/getMemberGroups](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/##UserId##%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B/getMemberGroups) API without using any npm package of angular.

I tried using http service, but getting below error

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token' from origin 'https://xxx.co' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Is there any another way to call Graph API for token and user get login user groups ?

Comment: Try to see the [implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#getting-access-tokens-silently-in-the-background) to get access token.

Answer (score 2):

It is not allowed to call `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/v2.0/token`
directly from a signal page application due to CORS. You should use MSAL for angular to do this. My code is based on [this angular official demo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-angular).

Pls go to `src/app/app.module.ts` to config your Azure Ad:

[image]

and run this demo first.

After you run this demo successfully,go to `profile.component.ts`, add codes below:

```
  getAccessTokenAndCallGraphAPI(){

    this.authService.acquireTokenPopup({
      scopes: ['GroupMember.Read.All']
    }).then(result=>{
      console.log("access token: "+ result.accessToken)

      const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type':  'application/json',
          Authorization: 'Bearer '+result.accessToken
        })}

      const reqBody = {
        "securityEnabledOnly": true
      }
      this.http.post("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user you want to query>/getMemberGroups",reqBody,httpOptions).toPromise().then(result=>{console.log(result)});
    })
  }
```

Call this function when init page:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getProfile();
    this.getAccessTokenAndCallGraphAPI();
  }
```

**result:**

[image]

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: An argument for 'interceptorConfig' was not provided. This error occurs in app.module with the above code